# Set empty design layout for a controller

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, css, rwd, design

I've created a controller that is displaying some html code retrieved from `orders.phtml` file :

```
<?php
class Envato_RecentProducts_OrderController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('newaves/orders.phtml')->toHtml();
    }
}
```

I usually create pages using CMS with selecting Empty layout in Design section, that way I have css theme classes imported in that page even if the page is empty:
[image]

That code retrieves the header and footer, it doesn't help as I only want an empty page :

```
$this->loadLayout();
$this->renderLayout();
```

How can I have the controller 'imports' the default theme/ css classes ?